# Xamarin.Android TextView doesn't raise change events when "Link SDK Assemblies" is selected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, xamarin-linker

I'm working on a project in Xamarin with MvvmCross, trying to use the linker to get the app size down for release on Android and iOS (no Forms.)

On Android, when I selected "Link SDK Assemblies Only", the project builds and runs with no crashes or error messages. But none of the `EditText` controls responds correctly when their text changes, their data bindings don't get updated, and their `Changed` event handlers don't get called.

When I select "Don't Link", everything works fine. Bindings are updated and event handlers are called.

I have looked at the [Xamarin Linker documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/), and I'm aware of how to ensure various assemblies, types and methods are preserved. My problem is I simply don't know what needs to be preserved, nor do I have any idea how to find out. I've tried tools like [bitdiffer](https://github.com/bitdiffer/bitdiffer) with no success.

Can anyone help me figure out what I need to preserve if anything?

Comment: Do you have a file called LinkerPleaseInclude in your Droid project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file to your Android project containing the following code:

```
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(TextView text)
    {
        text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
        text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;
    }
}
```

`EditText` is inheriting from `TextView` so this will take care of your problem by making the linker think you reference the `TextView.AfterTextChanged` event. You can find a reference Android LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/nuspec/DroidContent/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.pp).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is often seen if the LinkerPleaseInclude file is missing a reference to your EditText. The reason is that the linker strips everything not referenced/ used from your app. With a reference in the LinkerPleaseInclude file the linker will notice the usage and keeps the event handler.